# Are there any freely available WMS tile servers?

Tags: wms, tiles

I am looking for an open public endpoint to retrieve WMS map tiles from, for use with [leaflet maps](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms-options)

For clarity, I am not looking to set up a tile server or for tile server software.

It looks like the [NASA service is now closed](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/2011/11/03/nasas-onearth-has-been-abandoned/)

Comment: Do you need tiles or WMS - they are different things. Your link states the NASA tile service remains online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need WMS here you'll find the OpenGeo WMS server:

http://www.mapmatters.org/server/3222

and many others here:

http://www.mapmatters.org/keyword/WMS